# Classic asp page in VS2012 unable to open

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp-classic

I have a VS 2012 solution which contains a classic asp application (existing application I don't know why or how).

I am able to open the solution in VS 2012 but unable to open any classic asp file. While trying to open it closes VS 2012. I have Resharper too.

What is causing this issue?

Here is the solution file

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2012
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "Web", "http://localhost:6812", "{45E1C5CC-9D91-43E2-8F15-A344D84E4BA4}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        SccProjectName = "SAK"
        SccAuxPath = "SAK"
        SccLocalPath = "SAK"
        SccProvider = "SAK"
        UseIISExpress = "true"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/localhost_6812"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "Web\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_6812\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/localhost_6812"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "Web\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_6812\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        SlnRelativePath = "Web\"
        DefaultWebSiteLanguage = "Visual C#"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "someproject\", "NET\someproject\someproject\.csproj", "{07316417-EED7-4E5C-8161-88444DBC8A0A}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
        SccNumberOfProjects = 3
        SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
        SccTeamFoundationServer = http://someserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
        SccLocalPath0 = .
        SccWebProject1 = true
        SccProjectUniqueName1 = http://localhost:6812
        SccProjectName1 = Web
        SccLocalPath1 = Web
        SccProjectEnlistmentChoice1 = 2
        SccProjectUniqueName2 = NET\\someproject\\someproject.csproj
        SccProjectName2 = NET/someproject
        SccLocalPath2 = NET\\someproject
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {45E1C5CC-9D91-43E2-8F15-A344D84E4BA4}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {45E1C5CC-9D91-43E2-8F15-A344D84E4BA4}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {45E1C5CC-9D91-43E2-8F15-A344D84E4BA4}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {45E1C5CC-9D91-43E2-8F15-A344D84E4BA4}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {07316417-EED7-4E5C-8161-88444DBC8A0A}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {07316417-EED7-4E5C-8161-88444DBC8A0A}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {07316417-EED7-4E5C-8161-88444DBC8A0A}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {07316417-EED7-4E5C-8161-88444DBC8A0A}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: what's the error, exactly/ You may want to add a screenshot or something

Comment: no error or no error window or message it is just closing the VS 2012

Comment: You might enable visual studio logging too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms241272.aspx

Comment: Can you open the ASP file in any other editor, e.g. Notepad++? Try open it and save the file (checking encoding, etc.). Then reopen it again. It might be possible as well that VS2012 try to interprete the file and if HTML code is mixed in it it crashes while parsing. I had this issue once, try a very simple ASP file if it works in general.

Comment: Add: Some older ASP function pages are very long (old style :)). If your page has a fwe thousand lines, then my VS2012 crashed as well working on the page.

Comment: @YvesR i tried that it does for every asp page. i have some files which are just html content and couple of plain simple asp code .that closes VS 2012 too

Comment: In this case you should remove your users settings from VS2012 to reset to defaults.

Comment: Your project solution file is not creating the issue. Your user profile settings are damaged somehow. So backup your appdata/roaming/visualstudio folders, remove them and re-init studio again, try if this works.

Comment: @YvesR re-installing VS 2012 may solve the problem it is second option. i am trying to see to reset any setting to default

Comment: I had some crashes as well in the past and for me it helped to remove my profile. Reinstalling was not necessary.

Comment: @YvesR I don't see any folder Visual Studio under Appdata\Roaming\ ,And i don't see ActivityLog.xml(visual studio log file) anywhere in my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uninstalled VS2012 and installed again solved this issue
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with VS 2012 Professional running on Windows 8 Pro.  Downloading VS 2012 Update 3 fixed the problem for me.

[Link to VS 2012 Update 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305)